Player.iconImageUri() - Google Play Games API
My app is exclusively written in Jetpack Compose using Kotlin.
It looks like the Google Play Games Player.iconImageUrl is deprecated.  I'm struggling to implement the replacement, Player.iconImageUri.
I feel like I've gone back in time a couple years, since I'm using Views again.  Does anyone have a way to implement the links from iconImageUri without calling AndroidView from a @Composable?
I did find this super helpful post.  iconImageUrl can provide me an actual link so I can populate the image using a @Composable, but unfortunately, iconImageUri forces me to use the ImageManager, which only outputs an ImageView.

I have no experience with this API, but from the name it seems that it just returns a URI. Can't you just feed that to any image library that provides composables, like, f.e., Coil or Glide?

Nope.  It provides a Uri that looks something like content://com.google.android.gms.games.background/..., which I'm guessing is being called as a query rather than a URL
